# How to set the coordinate limits when x and y scales are very different?

Tags: r, ggplot2

## Goal

I want to plot cars using `ggplot2` and `ggbg::geom_car` (more details on `geom_car` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159087/is-it-possible-to-draw-diagrams-in-r/22207979#22207979)).

## Problem

The x and y scales are very different. The recorded x-coordinate of vehicles is way too large than the recorded y coordinate. This distorts the shape of car.

### Data

```
> dput(mdfs)
structure(list(frames = 41595L, ed_x_m = -7846.10309712287, ed_y_m = 85.7376740407815, 
    length_ed_m = 4.64, width_ed_m = 2.08, lv = "Ford1", lv_x_m = -7362.6827203125, 
    lv_y_m = 86.6492784667969, length_lv_m = 5.36448, width_lv_m = 1.9812, 
    fv = NA_character_, fv_x_m = NA_real_, fv_y_m = NA_real_, 
    length_fv_m = NA_real_, width_fv_m = NA_real_, lvt = "WhiteC2", 
    lvt_x_m = -7792.6745578125, lvt_y_m = 83.0061333984375, length_lvt_m = 5.035296, 
    width_lvt_m = 1.880616, fvt = NA_character_, fvt_x_m = NA_real_, 
    fvt_y_m = NA_real_, length_fvt_m = NA_real_, width_fvt_m = NA_real_), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### Plots that I tried:

```
ggplot(mdfs) +
  geom_car(aes(x=ed_x_m, y=ed_y_m, length=length_ed_m,
               width=width_ed_m, fill="ed")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=lv_x_m, y=lv_y_m, length=length_lv_m,
               width=width_lv_m, fill="lv")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=lvt_x_m, y=lvt_y_m, length=length_lvt_m,
               width=width_lvt_m, fill="lvt")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=fvt_x_m, y=fvt_y_m, length=length_fvt_m,
                 width=width_fvt_m, fill="fvt")) +
  ggtitle("Without coord_equal()")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mdfs) +
  geom_car(aes(x=ed_x_m, y=ed_y_m, length=length_ed_m,
               width=width_ed_m, fill="ed")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=lv_x_m, y=lv_y_m, length=length_lv_m,
               width=width_lv_m, fill="lv")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=lvt_x_m, y=lvt_y_m, length=length_lvt_m,
               width=width_lvt_m, fill="lvt")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=fvt_x_m, y=fvt_y_m, length=length_fvt_m,
                 width=width_fvt_m, fill="fvt")) +
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("With coord_equal()")
```

[image]

**How can I properly plot the cars?**

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue since the `ggbg` package is not available for `R v 4.0.2`. However, one approach might be to just rescale your x data and then alias the x axis with appropriate values. Then `coord_equal()` should work:

```
ggplot(mdfs) +
  geom_car(aes(x=ed_x_m/100, y=ed_y_m, length=length_ed_m,
               width=width_ed_m, fill="ed")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=lv_x_m/100, y=lv_y_m, length=length_lv_m,
               width=width_lv_m, fill="lv")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=lvt_x_m/100, y=lvt_y_m, length=length_lvt_m,
               width=width_lvt_m, fill="lvt")) +
  geom_car(aes(x=fvt_x_m/100, y=fvt_y_m, length=length_fvt_m,
                 width=width_fvt_m, fill="fvt")) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-78, -76, -74), labels = c(-7800, -7600, -7400)) +
  ggtitle("With coord_equal()")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried scaling as you did. But the problem is that the length of cars must be scaled as well, otherwise, the distance between cars is not the actual distance. If I do `length_ed_m/100`, then I am back at where I started (cars are distorted)

Comment: For reproducing: you don't need `ggbg` if you download the car image and create the `geom_car` from the code available in the linked question.